# Any way to search comments for amazon.com links

Tags: discussion

Some one corrected my comment (I deleted my comment) with a comment showing me an Amazon.com link listing retail copies of Windows 7, my Amazonfu cannot find any, would like the link or what search terms were used.

Comment: People can't edit comments...other then their own...what?

Comment: System builder is considered retail Windows 7 license

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment which makes it impossible for me to find it.

Comment: Comments aren't searchable using the SU search box, but Google does search them (I just tested a phrase from one of my own comments).  That won't help you, though, for a nebulous, generic search.  Even with filters, you would end up with a ridiculous number of hits unless you can remember some unique wording in the comment.

Comment: @Moab what would you want to search your comment history for? Mods can see a list of deleted comments for a user. I checked though and didn't see any amazon links in your deleted comments.

Comment: @nhinkle: It's somebody else's comment that has the link.

Comment: I just went to amazon.com and put "windows 7" in the search box.  Got this: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_0_9?url=search-alias%3Dsoftware&field-keywords=windows+7&sprefix=windows+7%2Caps%2C291